# rapid prototyping with webpack or similar

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, rapid-prototyping

I am wondering if there is a rapid prototyping tool that I can use to speed up static html and css development.

My workflow normally is to build the html and css first before any programming. 
I normally build the pages one by one and separate common elements into includes to keep it dry.

In the past I used PHP or something else to include everything together.

I am wondering if I can achieve this with webpack.

- I will have 1 html file / page
- In each html file I need to include html fragements from other static files
- I need LESS compilation ( I can do this with webpack )
- I also need hot-reload for css ( this is easy )
- I also need the hot-reload to work when I change an html fragment ( e.g. header of footer ) I need the whole page to reload

is there something out there I could use to do this ?

Thanks for looking

Comment: Look into [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

Comment: The Webpack Development Server makes a lot of this easy. It has hot reload, all that sort of thing. Very easy to set up, I have a seed project I use. I just copy it (it has a header/footer/router configs all ready to go), and then write the code. Also for really static stuff, you can just load HTML pages into a single component (so that you don't need a component every time you change a view).

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you want my webpack config and package.json files (which really is the crux of the whole thing) just message me. You run npm install and basically everything is set up, you run npm run watch and npm run serve and you're developing/reloading, you run npm run prodbuild and you get your bundle. Very easy.

Comment: Hi @TimConsolazio thanks for your message. Can you share it on github perhaps ?

Comment: Yeah I could put together another seed project and post it. Will have to wait a while, need to run out the door a few hours.

Comment: Hi, great that sounds fantastic of course I am happy to wait, just le me know when you have it! Thanks again !!!

Comment: Here you go. I just whacked it together and tested, you download/clone, follow the README.md instructions, and you're up and running. Note (as far as I can see) you'll be using the latest versions of Webpack (2) and so on, I checked all the major versions and such. https://github.com/tcoz/ang2-babel-webpack. For example of how to just load different web pages into the same component (making basic static content MUCH EASIER to work with), see the article I wrote on http://www.tcoz.com/newtcoz/#/errata, *ng-include in Angular 2?*

Comment: Hi, Cool thanks a lot!! I am sure others will find this useful as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) and a template engine of your choice which supports fragments/partials.

Check out [The template option](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md) of the HTML Webpack Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of need for this, maybe you should build your own tool
that is suited to your needs.

Here are some possible options that you might consider:

- `express` and some templating engine (`pug` or `mustache`)
- `webpack` with HTML Plugin as suggested by @floriangosse
- `grunt` or `gulp` with watcher plugins for compiling your templates and stylesheets
- `browserSync` for reloading stuff in the browser

I would go with webpack since it provides a lot of this out of the 
box (+ loaders). I found it helpful to create a small repository that contains webpack configurations for dev, production and some base configuration you can inherit from, a public folder with your html and either npm scripts or some gulp/grunt file for firing it up.

**edit** I am not suggesting to build your own tool but rather your own customized tool suite